# How to build base knowlage of sharepoint 2007

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2007

I am looking for a sharepoint 2007 guide to help build base knowlage. I would love any direction you guys can provide.

What are some good ways or guides to build a solid base knowlage of Sharepoint 2007?

Comment: For a second, I thought you were building a knowledge-base *IN* SharePoint, but after re-reading, you are trying to get started with SharePoint.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

We started by [dog fooding] Sharepoint.  We installed a copy on a VM, just for our team.  We tried to make demos of each of the features (scheduling, url lists, my page, etc) as well as sub-sites that showed the differnces between the site templates.  It helped us determine which were really useful for us and which ones didn't meet our needs.

Answer (score 0):

They have a knowledge base template for SharePoint that you can download:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb407286.aspx

Once you have the site created, the rest should fall into place.  Just add knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I found Inside Microsoft SharePoint Server 2007 by Patrick Tissegham to be a great resource for getting started with MOSS 2007.

[http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft-Office-SharePoint-Server/dp/0735623686/ref=sr_1_29?ie=UTF8&qid=1289919494&sr=8-29](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623686)

Also, Inside Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 by Ted Pattison and Daniel Larson -

[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Windows-SharePoint-Services-Developer/dp/0735623201/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1289919646&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623201)